# pre-populating fields, angularjs controller doesn't recognize the values

Tags: angularjs

I am pre-populating fields from the Facebook API:

```
$("#inputParentName").val(response.name);
$("#inputParentEmail").val(response.email);
$("#inputParentBirthday").val(response.birthday);
```

In my AngularJS service I have the following function:

```
vm.addParent = function () {
    alert(vm.inputParentName);
    alert(vm.inputParentBirthday);
    alert(vm.inputParentEmail);
```

When this function gets called the pre-populated fields display as 'undefined' in the alert boxes.  However if I type in the values I get the actual text that was typed in.

What do I need to do, to have my AngularJS code recognize the pre-populated values?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `$("#some_id").val(some_val)` will only set the `value` property of an HTML element. I don't see how you expect that to correspond with a property in `vm`

Comment: you should avoid using jquery when you are using angular unless there is absolutely no other way to accomplish your task.

Comment: @Claies - right now I'm working throught FB API so until I get a better handle on that, I'm working in a hybrid form.

Comment: as far as I'm aware, you don't need jquery to use the Facebook API.....

Comment: @Claies I found an example of how to use AngularJS and FB API...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery to populate input field. What you should be doing instead is populating your angular scope value assigned to the ng-model of your input field

i.e.

```
<input type="text" name"inputParentName" id="inputParentName" ng-model="vm.inputParentName">
<input type="text" name"inputParentEmail" id="inputParentEmail" ng-model="vm.inputParentEmail">
<input type="text" name"inputParentBirthday" id="inputParentBirthday" ng-model="vm.inputParentBirthday">
```

should be populated not by using jQuery but by assigning the value using angular's scope. (this code likely goes in your controller)

```
$scope.vm = {
  'inputParentName': response.name,
  'inputParentEmail': response.email,
  'inputParentBirthday': response.birthday
}
```

Then the values will show up where intended....

(I am guessing at your html and javascript, but this is an approximate guess)

Do yourself a favor and avoid trying to marry jQuery and Angular - it can be done, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

To further clarify the reason that your values are not assigned to the model is that Angular has no clue they are present. Updating a field through a query element rather than ngModel bypasses Angular's data binding. Either calling for a $scope . digest after or placing the assignments into a $scope.$apply(function () {}) would work but is not recommended. Do as suggested and set the values with the built in models.

Comment: is there a way to pass the response object I'm getting from the facebook api to my controller?

Comment: I would need to see what format it is in, but if it is in JSON you can just set it as $scope.facebookAPIObject = returnedFacebookAPIObject;